# Select box as category filter isn't working on Chrome, IE.

Tags: jquery, html, css, gridview, filter

I'm using this category filter for posts on homepage [[demo]](http://demo.webcodo.net/switch-products-view-grid-list-jquery-with-filter-and-cookie/). When I tried to add a select box as an additional filter, it was only functioning on Firefox. [Please check out my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfVAH/555/). Here's part of the code in which I added a selector for the select box:

```
    /* filter */
    $(".category-menu ul li,.category-menu select option").click(function(){
        var CategoryID = $(this).data('category');
        $('.category-menu ul li').removeClass('cat-active');
        $(this).addClass('cat-active');

        $('.prod-cnt').each(function(){
            if(($(this).hasClass(CategoryID)) == false){
               $(this).css({'display':'none'});
            };
        });
        $('.'+CategoryID).fadeIn(); 

    });
});
```

Is the selector `.category-menu select option` wrong and preventing the filter from functioning on any browsers except Firefox?

You can find out more information about the filter on the [explanation page](http://www.webcodo.net/grid-list-view-with-jquery-category-filter-cookie-support/#.UvxT487m5RU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` has a change event and not a `click` event on it's option.So you need to register a `change` event on the `select` of yours.

This is what i can help you with if this is only thing that you want

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/UfVAH/558/)

============================================

For the selection of `All` just put the following code

```
if($(this).find('option:selected').hasClass('cat-active') == true)
{
    $('.prod-cnt').show();
    return false;
}
```

directly at first line. may be the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/UfVAH/569/) will explain more.